# converting and concatenating multiple rows into columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using Dynamic PIVOT approach to convert the dynamic rows into columns and its working fine for me. But I have one more requirement on top of it. I am using below query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
+ QUOTENAME(case when d.col = 'STN_CODE' then col+'_'+cast(seq as      varchar(10))
else col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10)) end) 
from ( select row_number() over(partition by   POF_FILE_ID,
 PART_PFX,
 PART_BASE,PART_SFX
 order by STN_CODE,PROCESS_ELEMENT) seq
                  from APT_POINT_OF_FIT
                ) t
                cross apply
                (
                  select 'STN_CODE', 1 union all
                  select 'PROCESS_ELEMENT', 2
                ) d (col, so)
                group by col, so, seq
                order by seq, so
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

 set @query = 'SELECT POF_FILE_ID,PART_PFX,PART_BASE,PART_SFX, ' + 
 @cols   + ' 
 from 
 (
  select t.POF_FILE_ID,t.PART_PFX,t.PART_BASE,t.PART_SFX, 
  col = case 
  when c.col = ''STN_CODE'' then col+''_''+cast(seq as varchar(10))
  else col+''_''+cast(seq as varchar(10))
  end,
  value
  from 
   (
    select POF_FILE_ID,PART_PFX,PART_BASE,PART_SFX,STN_CODE,  
    PROCESS_ELEMENT,
    row_number() over(partition by  POF_FILE_ID,
    PART_PFX,
    PART_BASE,
    PART_SFX
    order by STN_CODE) seq
    from APT_POINT_OF_FIT
    ) t
    cross apply
    (
        select ''STN_CODE'', STN_CODE union all
        select ''PROCESS_ELEMENT'', PROCESS_ELEMENT
     ) c (col, value)
   ) x
    pivot 
        (
            max(value)
            for col in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

  execute sp_executesql @query;
```

My requirement is to insert the values in separate columns till seq 8 and concatenate all other column values coming after that seq(> seq8).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!